TextInput double tap required for keyboard when used as child component
The Problem:
Upon loading the app, when the user selects(taps) the input, the keyboard doesn't show up on the first time. Only after deselecting the input by tapping anywhere else on the screen, and then again tapping on the same input will make the keyboard show up. And this double-tap is only required once after the initial load. Single-taps continue to work after tapping on and off the input.

What I think is the reason
I notice when I moved the inputs into a child component, this issue started happening. However it seems to work fine if I write out the duplicated code. I think the setState is causing the child to re-render initially, and then it doesn't again once the setState is called again.
The Code

App.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "react-native-expo-template",
    "slug": "react-native-expo-template",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scheme": "msauth",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "backgroundColor": "#001689",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#001689"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.jamespageced.reactnativeexpotemplate",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#001689"
      },
      "package": "com.jamespageced.reactnativeexpotemplate",
      "versionCode": 1
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          "photosPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your photos",
          "cameraPermissions": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your camera"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}

babel.config.js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', 'babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      [
        require.resolve('babel-plugin-module-resolver'),
        {
          extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.android.js', '.android.tsx', '.ios.js', '.ios.tsx'],
          alias: {
            '@': './',
            '@app': './app'
          }
        }
      ]
    ]
  };
};

package.json
{
  "name": "react-native-expo-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "ts:check": "tsc",
    "dev-android": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npx expo run:android --port 8082",
    "dev-ios": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development npx expo run:ios --port 8082",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

App.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
import { Home } from '@app/screens';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <Home />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

app/screens/index.ts
export { default as Home } from './Home';

app/screens/Home.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Keyboard, Pressable, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback, View } from 'react-native';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import type { PermissionStatus } from 'expo-modules-core';
import { useQuery } from 'react-query';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Header, InputWithCamera } from '@app/screens/homeChildren';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  formContainer: {
    width: '100%',
    padding: 20,
    gap: 20,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#999'
  },
  cameraButton: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: 48,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
  },
  cameraButtonDisabled: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#cccccc',
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginLeft: 10
  }
});

export default function Home() {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState<PermissionStatus>(ImagePicker.PermissionStatus.DENIED);
  const [inputOneText, setInputOneText] = useState('');
  const [inputTwoText, setInputTwoText] = useState('');
  const [isInputOneActive, setIsInputOneActive] = useState(false);
  const [isInputTwoActive, setIsInputTwoActive] = useState(false);

  const { isFetching: isFetchingScreenData } = useQuery(
    ['transactionStartScreenLoadData', isFocused],
    async () => {
      if (!isFocused) return undefined;
      const { status } = await ImagePicker.getCameraPermissionsAsync();
      return status;
    },
    {
      onError: (error: any) => {
        if (!isFocused) return undefined;
        return undefined;
      },
      onSuccess: (resp: PermissionStatus) => {
        if (resp === undefined) return;
        setCameraPermission(resp);
        return undefined;
      }
    }
  );

  // functions
  const handleSelectInputs = (selectedInputActiveState?: string | null) => {
    if (selectedInputActiveState === null) {
      Keyboard.dismiss();
    }
    if (selectedInputActiveState === 'isInputOneActive') {
      setIsInputOneActive(true);
    } else if (selectedInputActiveState === 'isInputTwoActive') {
      setIsInputTwoActive(true);
    }
    if (selectedInputActiveState !== 'isInputOneActive') setIsInputOneActive(false);
    if (selectedInputActiveState !== 'isInputTwoActive') setIsInputTwoActive(false);
  };
  const isCameraDisabled = () => {
    return cameraPermission === ImagePicker.PermissionStatus.DENIED;
  };

  // setup
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFocused) {
      handleSelectInputs(null);
    }
  }, [isFocused]);
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => handleSelectInputs(null)}>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff', ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject }}>
        <Header title="Main Title" subTitle="Sub Title" />
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <InputWithCamera
            placeholderText="Input One"
            isInputActive={isInputOneActive}
            inputText={inputOneText}
            setInputToActive={() => handleSelectInputs('isInputOneActive')}
            setInputText={setInputOneText}
          >
            <Pressable
              disabled={isCameraDisabled()}
              style={isCameraDisabled() ? styles.cameraButtonDisabled : styles.cameraButton}
              onPress={() => handleSelectInputs(null)}
            >
              <MaterialIcons name="camera-alt" size={24} color={isCameraDisabled() ? '#333333' : '#2370B3'} />
            </Pressable>
          </InputWithCamera>
          <InputWithCamera
            placeholderText="Input Two"
            isInputActive={isInputTwoActive}
            inputText={inputTwoText}
            setInputToActive={() => handleSelectInputs('isInputTwoActive')}
            setInputText={setInputTwoText}
          >
            <Pressable
              disabled={isCameraDisabled()}
              style={isCameraDisabled() ? styles.cameraButtonDisabled : styles.cameraButton}
              onPress={() => handleSelectInputs(null)}
            >
              <MaterialIcons name="camera-alt" size={24} color={isCameraDisabled() ? '#333333' : '#2370B3'} />
            </Pressable>
          </InputWithCamera>
          <View style={{ marginBottom: 100 }} />
        </View>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}

app/screens/homeChildren/index.ts
export { default as Header } from './Header';
export { default as InputWithCamera } from './InputWithCamera';

app/screens/homeChildren/InputWithCamera.tsx
import React, { Dispatch, ReactNode, SetStateAction } from 'react';
import {
  NativeSyntheticEvent,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TextInputFocusEventData,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View
} from 'react-native';

interface Props {
  placeholderText: string;
  isInputActive: boolean;
  inputText: string;
  maxInputHeight: number;
  setInputToActive: (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputFocusEventData>) => void;
  setInputText: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
  children: ReactNode;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1 },
  showInputSecondBoarder: {
    padding: 2,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#03A9F4'
  },
  hideInputSecondBoarder: {
    height: 0,
    padding: 2
  },
  inputContainerOuter: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#03A9F4'
  },
  activePlaceholderContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -12,
    left: 16,
    zIndex: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
  },
  inactivePlaceholderContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 14,
    left: 16,
    zIndex: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff'
  },
  inputContainerInner: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  input: { paddingHorizontal: 10, backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }
});

export default function InputWithCamera({
  placeholderText,
  isInputActive,
  inputText,
  maxInputHeight,
  setInputToActive,
  setInputText,
  children
}: Props): ReactNode {
  return (
    <View style={{ ...styles.container, marginBottom: maxInputHeight - 7 }}>
      <View
        style={
          isInputActive ? { ...styles.showInputSecondBoarder, height: maxInputHeight } : styles.hideInputSecondBoarder
        }
      >
        <View style={{ ...styles.inputContainerOuter, height: maxInputHeight - 7 }}>
          <View
            style={isInputActive || inputText ? styles.activePlaceholderContainer : styles.inactivePlaceholderContainer}
            pointerEvents="none"
          >
            <Text>
              {placeholderText} <Text style={{ color: 'red' }}>*</Text>
            </Text>
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.inputContainerInner} activeOpacity={1}>
            <TextInput
              onChangeText={(text: string) => setInputText(text)}
              onFocus={setInputToActive}
              style={{ ...styles.input, height: maxInputHeight - 9 }}
              placeholder=""
              value={inputText}
              autoCorrect={false}
              spellCheck={false}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          {children}
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

InputWithCamera.defaultProps = {
  maxInputHeight: 57
};

app/screens/homeChildren/Header.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

interface Props {
  title: string;
  subTitle: string;
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: 40,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#f4fcff'
  },
  iconContainer: { backgroundColor: '#d6e7f8', padding: 10, borderRadius: 50, marginRight: 10 },
  hideIconContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 30,
    width: 30,
    marginLeft: 'auto',
    backgroundColor: '#2370B3',
    borderRadius: 50
  },
  titleContainer: { flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column' },
  titleText: { flexShrink: 1, color: '#000000', opacity: 0.67 }
});

export default function Header({ title, subTitle }: Props): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
        <MaterialIcons name="fact-check" size={24} color="#4D688B" />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text numberOfLines={2} style={{ ...styles.titleText, fontSize: 18 }}>
          {title}
        </Text>
        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{ ...styles.titleText, fontSize: 16 }}>
          {subTitle}
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}


I figured out the issue. It was because the 2nd border view was causing some sort of interference, so I added it as a position absolute and made sure it doesn't wrap around the input.
style changes...
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, position: 'relative' },
  inputSecondBoarder: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: -4,
    right: -4,
    bottom: -4,
    left: -4,
    zIndex: 1,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#03A9F4'
  },
  inputContainerOuter: {
    zIndex: 2,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#03A9F4'
  },
...

JSX Changes
    <View style={{ ...styles.container, marginBottom: maxInputHeight - 7 }}>
      <View style={isInputActive ? styles.inputSecondBoarder : {}} />
      <View style={{ ...styles.inputContainerOuter, height: maxInputHeight - 7 }}>
...
...
...
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {children}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

Note: don't forget to remove the related ending </View>
